How to dynamically bind tcp connections
I want to build a webserver which allows users via a website to make VNC connections to a number of VNC hosts behind a firewall. Each user has access to different VNC hosts.
I need some advice how to accomplish this, or at least, what terms should I search for?
So, in short, a user logs in through a webinterface. The webserver checks what VNC hosts do this user have access to, and then serves the user with a list of links to different VNC hosts. When the user clicks on one of these links, he should connect to a server, which then redirect / proxies this connection thru the firewall and to a certain IP-adress of the listing VNC host.
